# Are there "female" 2.54mm screw terminals?

Tags: prototyping, pins

There are a variety of male screw terminals with pins one can solder into a PCB.  Are there female screw terminals that fit directly over the 2.54mm pitch/spaced "jumper" pins that small boards like the Teensy stick into breakout boards?

I've found [boards](http://www.mikroe.com/add-on-boards/various/easyconnect2/) that do 2.54mm, but they're huge. I've also found [3.5mm pitch](http://www.metz-connect.com/en/products/311661) female pluggable screw terminals.  Yet, nothing small and 2.54mm so far.

Comment: I've seen them in the dim and distant past. Phoenix connectors rings a bell but whether they were 0.1" I can't remember

Comment: Mouser says no "pluggable terminal blocks" with 2.54mm pitch and screw termination style. All the "terminal blocks" satisfying these requirements look pin based.  Very strange that 2.54mm pitch exists for "male" pins, but not as pluggable/female.

Comment: For single-row headers, it would be relatively straightforward to solder the pins of a screw terminal block directly to a female header strip. For dual-row, you're pretty much going to need a PCB of some sort.

Comment: Male 0.1" pitch screw terminals themselves are hard to find for cheap anyway. Most standard screw terminals are 5mm pitch, twice the 0.1" size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pluggable 2.54 mm screw terminals with female spring-clamps. Here is one example:

[image: Pluggable 2.54 mm pitch]

The datasheet is essentially one page:

[image: Datasheet]

The source of the above is [here](http://www.china-terminals.com/products/Buy-good-Quality-Pluggable-Terminal-Block-125V-4A-KF12EY-pitch-2-54mm-1304109.html), but other sources show up in a web search.

Comment: These are like the phoenix(?) ones I saw many moons ago or maybe I was smoking the pot (another question LOL)

Comment: @Andyaka  Smoking the potentiometer?  You'll see things when you smoke potentiometer.